# How to add a minor grid in boxplots in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a vertical minor grid between two major grids in a boxplot with discrete x variables in *ggplot2*.

This is the sample:

```
boxplot <- ggplot(data = mtcars ,aes(x = as.factor(cyl),y=wt, fill=as.factor(am))) + geom_boxplot()
boxplot
```

As seen from the visualization, it can be unclear which box belongs to which x label because the major vertical grid is separating the two boxes at the same x-variable (it may not be an issue here, but it does become problematic when there are many x variables and narrow boxes). Therefore, I am thinking of adding a minor grid in the middle of each major grid. I tried using the "minor grid.x" in ggplot2, shown below, but I could not see any added lines.

```
boxplot + theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(color="black"))
```

I've looked over related posts on setting gridlines, but it seems that they are focused on continuous x variables, and is not applicable to box plots.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update thanks to @Allan Cameron:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars ,aes(x =factor(cyl),y=wt, fill=as.factor(am))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(1.5, 2.5),linetype="dashed",colour="green",size=1)
```

First answer:

Are you looking for such a solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars ,aes(x =factor(cyl),y=wt, fill=as.factor(am))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=1.5),linetype="dashed",colour="green",size=1)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=2.5),linetype="dashed",colour="green",size=1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is the best approach TarJae, but you only need a single `geom_vline` call. Just remove the `aes` and use `xintercept = c(1.5, 2.5)`

Comment: Thank you very much @Allan Cameron. I will update.

Comment: Thank you so much TarJae and Allan! This answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and modify the values of the theme and see what works better for you:

```
boxplot + 
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "blue",
                                      size = 0.5,
                                      linetype = 2),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = "red",
                                        size = 0.25,
                                        linetype = 1),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "green",
                                      size = 0.5,
                                      linetype = 3)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! However, I want to have a vertical grid to make clear the separation between each x-variable. I've modified my question to make this point clearer.

Comment: Now I added that vertical grid. I just forget it :P